# Background image on ul repeats expands to child elements

Tags: css

I have a menu with a background image on ul level which spans all the menu items [main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDbtO.png)
How do I prevent the image to expand down when a child element is opened? [child menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc9Eg.png)
I have tried to set   background:none on the child element but that is not helping

```
<div class="well _menu">
    <ul class="nav menu navbar-nav nav-pills mod-list nav-hover">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AGENDA</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">INSCHRIJVEN</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">INSCHRIJVEN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TARIEVEN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OVER WWJ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.well {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: #fff;
}
.well ul {
  background:url(../images/menubalk.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.well ul li{
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.well .nav-child{
  width:180px ;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.well .dropdown-menu{
  position:relative;
}
.well .dropdown-menu ul {
  background:none ;
}
.well .nav-child ul li{
  float: none;
  width: 100%
}
.well .nav-child li{
  display: contents;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the background explicitly to **only the direct children** of `.well`, you can avoid the current behaviour:

You do this by adding a `>` (child combinator) in between.

```css
.well > ul {
  background:url(../images/menubalk.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

> The **child combinator** (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the direct children of elements matched by the first.

Read more [about child combinator at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

Second problem, the vertical expansion of the menu background, can be fixed by adjusting these selectors.

1. Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.well > ul`
2. Adjust the CSS for the dropdown item class:

```css
.well .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
```

It will position the submenu without taking the parent into account. That's why `overflow: hidden` needs to be removed, otherwise it would not be visible.

[image: Outcome of adjusted changes]

Comment: Thanks Roy,

That removed the background for the child elements, but kept the main image to be expanded across 3 lines
You can check the behaviour here: https://www.greg-baud.nl/wwjtest/index.php/wwj-inschrijven/wwj-inschrijven-2.html